# to determine if the results of two arbitrary sql statements are the same

Tags: java, nlp

In a nl2sql scenario，different LLMs generates different sql statements for a certain natural language query. How can I write codes to determine if the results of these sql statements are the same or not?

For a certain natural language query, different LLMs may generate different sql statements selecting different rows from a table( or maybe even from different tables).

Firstly I can determine these sql statements are essentially the same by handling them in a string way: deleting additional whitespaces and other operations. But it is obviously not enough.

Wit JDBC ResultSet, I think I can figure out if different sql statements have the same count of results(the count of records in the resultset). But for a single resultset, how can I determine how many columns it have, and what the data type it is for a single column? Without these information, I cannot compare the sql statements generated by LLMs in a column data prospect.

Can this task be accomplished by writing codes or not?

Comment: but if you want to get the number of columns in a result set, you will have to use the ResultSetMetaData class to get the column count, then you can use it on your result set to get each column (field) by the index

Comment: This link contains what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24178360/16034206. The accepted answer shows how to get the ResultSetMetaData, and the answer below that will show how to get the Type of the column using the ResultSetMetaData

Comment: You could try passing the value of each cell returned through a hash function e.g. MurmurHash. 

If the hash is the same you know the result sets are identical. 
This is faster than constructing a very big String out of all the cells